# django, ajax, jquery

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-templates, django-views

friends, I'm really freaking out, do not install this application dajax django and now try to do it manually and nothing to make it, the idea is to send from the template, given a variable and return the same variable as a warning, would welcome help me this crazy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = 'Joe';
    function my_js_callback(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/app/test",
            data: {
                    'name': name
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

@login_required
def app_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST.getlist('name')[0]
        message = name
    else:
        message = "Not Ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: what is the point of doing that? You might aswell display the data you already have on the client side inside the html

Comment: Please try re-writing your question. At the moment, it's not comprehensible. Please explain what you want to happen, and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vista
----------------------------------------------------
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def app_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            info = '"%s"' % request
            return HttpResponse(info)


html
----------------------------------------------------
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myEvent = {id: '12345', end: '12345', allDay: '12345'};
        function my_js_callback(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/app/test/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: $.toJSON(myEvent),
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    alert('OK');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```